# How to add catalog price rule condition in magento2

Tags: magento2, module, backend, catalog-price-rules

I have added to custom module to add catalog price rule condition. how to 
Add Rule Condition in My custom module, I have also added Rule file and Condition.

```
$renderer = $this->_rendererFieldset->setTemplate('Emipro_Seo::promo/fieldset.phtml')->setNewChildUrl($this->getUrl('catalog_rule/promo_catalog/newConditionHtml/form/rule_conditions_fieldset'));
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'conditions_fieldset',
            ['legend' => __('Conditions (don\'t add conditions if rule is applied to all products)')]
        )->setRenderer($renderer);

        $fieldset->addField(
            'conditions',
            'text',
            ['name' => 'conditions', 'label' => __('Conditions'), 'title' => __('Conditions'), 'required' => true]
        )->setRule(
            $model
        )->setRenderer(
            $this->_conditions
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setep: 1. Add this file in Block folder

`Vender\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Index\Edit\Tab`

```
namespace Vender\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Index\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface;

class Conditions extends Generic implements TabInterface
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset
     */
    protected $_rendererFieldset;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions
     */
    protected $_conditions;

    private $ruleFactory;

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rendererFieldset = $rendererFieldset;
        $this->_conditions = $conditions;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }


    private function getRuleFactory()
    {
        if ($this->ruleFactory === null) {
            $this->ruleFactory = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\CatalogRule\Model\RuleFactory');
        }
        return $this->ruleFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getTabClass()
    {
        return null;
    }



    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Conditions');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Conditions');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('\Magento\CatalogRule\Controller\RegistryConstants::CURRENT_CATALOG_RULE_ID');

        if (!$model) {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('rule_id');
            $model = $this->getRuleFactory()->create();
            $model->load($id);
        }
        $fieldsetId = 'conditions_fieldset';
        $formName = 'catalog_rule_form';

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('rule_');

        $newChildUrl = $this->getUrl(
            'catalog_rule/promo_catalog/newConditionHtml/form/' . $model->getConditionsFieldSetId($formName),
            ['form_namespace' => $formName]
        );

        $renderer = $this->_rendererFieldset->setTemplate('Magento_CatalogRule::promo/fieldset.phtml')
                            ->setNewChildUrl($newChildUrl)
                            ->setFieldSetId($model->getConditionsFieldSetId($formName));

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            $fieldsetId,
            [
                'legend' => __(
                    'Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met (leave blank for all products).'
                )
            ]
        )->setRenderer(
            $renderer
        );


        $fieldset->addField(
            'conditions',
            'text',
            ['name' => 'conditions', 'label' => __('Conditions'), 'title' => __('Conditions')]
        )->setRule(
            $model
        )->setRenderer(
            $this->_conditions
        );

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setConditionFormName($model->getConditions(), $formName);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

}
```

Step: 2 Add this code in layout edit file

`frontendname_index_edit.xml`

```
<referenceContainer name="left">
        <block class="Vender\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Chartlist\Edit\Tabs" name="vender_module_edit_tabs">
            <block class="Vender\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Chartlist\Edit\Tab\Conditions" name="vender_module_tab_conditions"/>
            <action method="addTab">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">conditions_section</argument>
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">vender_module_tab_conditions</argument>
            </action>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Thankx You i have try this way ... thank You.. :)

Comment: brother i have try this way but can't disply Condition and all page is black only disply magento header .. :)

Comment: Can You send me your Files.

Comment: i am add your code only change vendor name and module name..

Comment: and i have add TAB.php file added tab for condition

Comment: Your Way is right Add Your Code have work properly but condition and rule save in Magento core table to save data i have save condition and rule in my custome table ... :) what can i do ???

Comment: You can change from your save controller . https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143882/how-to-get-maching-products-based-on-rule-conditions/146233#146233

Comment: what can i change in save file generally save controller not change only change in ID and model and all code same in all save controller...

Comment: Above My Condition image i have added but not rendere Condition

Comment: $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('\Magento\CatalogRule\Controller\RegistryConstants::CURRENT_CATALOG_RULE_ID'); change registry

Comment: thankx Saurabh Jain :)

Comment: after save the condition, saved condition data is not showing in edit form.

Comment: @SaurabhTaletiya condition field's data not getting save controller, you can check my question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310847/not-getting-value-of-condition-rule-in-save

Answer (score 1):

> Follow Below Steps:

**Step-1:** Create **registration.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendoreName_AddConditionFiled',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step-2:** Create **module.xml** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/etc**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled" setup_version="1.0.1">
        <sequence>
           <module name="Magento_Checkout"></module>
           <module name="Magento_Catalog"></module>
       </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step-3:** Create **InstallSchema.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Setup**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        if (!$installer->tableExists('VendoreName_custom_condition')) {
            $tableName = $installer->getTable('VendoreName_custom_condition');
            $table = $installer->getConnection()
                ->newTable($tableName)
                ->addColumn(
                    'rule_id',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    10,
                    [
                        'identity' => true,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'primary' => true,
                    ],
                    'Rule ID'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'rule_status',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    [
                        'nullable' => true,
                        'default' => null,
                    ],
                    'Rule Status'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'rule_name',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    255,
                    [
                        'nullable' => true,
                        'default' => null,
                    ],
                    'Rule Name'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'conditions_serialized',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    '2M',
                    [],
                    'Conditions Serialized'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'actions_serialized',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    '2M',
                    [],
                    'Actions Serialized'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'create_date',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                    null,
                    [
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT,
                    ],
                    'Create Date Time'
                )
                ->setComment('VendoreName Demo For Condition Field')
                ->setOption('type', 'InnoDB')
                ->setOption('charset', 'utf8');
            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        }
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Here conditions_serialized and actions_serialized are used to store condition field value. So you must be add into you table. After creating table we add resource model and collection. Our Model name is CustomCondition.

**Step-4:** Create **CustomCondition.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Model**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model;

use VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition as CustomConditionResourceModel;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address;
use Magento\Rule\Model\AbstractModel;

class CustomCondition extends AbstractModel
{
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'VendoreName_addconditionfiled';
    protected $_eventObject = 'rule';
    protected $condCombineFactory;
    protected $condProdCombineF;
    protected $validatedAddresses = [];
    protected $_selectProductIds;
    protected $_displayProductIds;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $condCombineFactory,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory $condProdCombineF,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->condCombineFactory = $condCombineFactory;
        $this->condProdCombineF = $condProdCombineF;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $localeDate, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init(CustomConditionResourceModel::class);
        $this->setIdFieldName('rule_id');
    }

    public function getConditionsInstance()
    {
        return $this->condCombineFactory->create();
    }

    public function getActionsInstance()
    {
        return $this->condCombineFactory->create();
    }

    public function hasIsValidForAddress($address)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        return isset($this->validatedAddresses[$addressId]) ? true : false;
    }

    public function setIsValidForAddress($address, $validationResult)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        $this->validatedAddresses[$addressId] = $validationResult;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsValidForAddress($address)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        return isset($this->validatedAddresses[$addressId]) ? $this->validatedAddresses[$addressId] : false;
    }

    private function _getAddressId($address)
    {
        if ($address instanceof Address) {
            return $address->getId();
        }
        return $address;
    }

    public function getConditionsFieldSetId($formName = '')
    {
        return $formName . 'rule_conditions_fieldset_' . $this->getId();
    }

    public function getActionFieldSetId($formName = '')
    {
        return $formName . 'rule_actions_fieldset_' . $this->getId();
    }

    public function getMatchProductIds()
    {
        $productCollection = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
            '\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection'
        );
        $productFactory = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
            '\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory'
        );
        $this->_selectProductIds = [];
        $this->setCollectedAttributes([]);
        $this->getConditions()->collectValidatedAttributes($productCollection);
        \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
            '\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Iterator'
        )->walk(
            $productCollection->getSelect(),
            [[$this, 'callbackValidateProductCondition']],
            [
                'attributes' => $this->getCollectedAttributes(),
                'product' => $productFactory->create(),
            ]
        );
        return $this->_selectProductIds;
    }

    public function callbackValidateProductCondition($args)
    {
        $product = clone $args['product'];
        $product->setData($args['row']);
        $websites = $this->_getWebsitesMap();
        foreach ($websites as $websiteId => $defaultStoreId) {
            $product->setStoreId($defaultStoreId);
            if ($this->getConditions()->validate($product)) {
                $this->_selectProductIds[] = $product->getId();
            }
        }
    }

    protected function _getWebsitesMap()
    {
        $map = [];
        $websites = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
            '\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'
        )->getWebsites();
        foreach ($websites as $website) {
            if ($website->getDefaultStore() === null) {
                continue;
            }
            $map[$website->getId()] = $website->getDefaultStore()->getId();
        }
        return $map;
    }
}
```

**Step-5:** Create **CustomCondition.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Model/ResourceModel**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class CustomCondition extends AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('VendoreName_custom_condition', 'rule_id');
    }
}
```

**Step-6:** Create **Collection.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Model/ResourceModel/CustomCondition**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition;

use VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\CustomCondition as CustomConditionModel;
use VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition as CustomConditionResourceModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            CustomConditionModel::class,
            CustomConditionResourceModel::class
        );
    }
}
```

**Step-7:** Create **Collection.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Model/ResourceModel/CustomCondition/Grid**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition\Grid;

use VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition\Collection as CustomConditionCollection;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document as CustomConditionModel;

class Collection extends CustomConditionCollection implements \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface
{
    protected $aggregations;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = CustomConditionModel::class,
        $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }

    public function getAggregations()
    {
        return $this->aggregations;
    }

    public function setAggregations($aggregations)
    {
        $this->aggregations = $aggregations;
    }

    public function getAllIds($limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        return $this->getConnection()->fetchCol($this->_getAllIdsSelect($limit, $offset), $this->_bindParams);
    }

    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function setSearchCriteria(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function getTotalCount()
    {
        return $this->getSize();
    }

    public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function setItems(array $items = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Step-8:** Create **di.xml** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/etc**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <virtualType name="VendoreNameAddConditionFiledFilterPool"
                 type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="VendoreNameAddConditionFiledFilterPool"
                 type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">VendoreNameAddConditionFiledFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <type name="VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">VendoreName_custom_condition</argument>
            <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">VendoreName_custom_condition_grid_collection</argument>
            <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">VendoreName_custom_condition_grid_collection</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_condition_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>

    </type>
</config>
```

**Step-9:** Create **routes.xml** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/etc/adminhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="addconditionfiled" frontName="addconditionfiled">
            <module name="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled" before="Magento_Backend"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Step-10:** Create **Index.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/Controller/Adminhtml/Index**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Add Rules'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**Step-11:** Create **menu.xml** at **app/code/VendoreName/AddConditionFiled/etc/adminhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Magento/Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
   <menu>
        <add id="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled::VendoreName_addconditionfiled"
             title="VendoreName - Add Condition Field"
             translate="title"
             module="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled"
             sortOrder="10"
             parent="Magento_Backend::marketing"
             resource="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled::VendoreName_addconditionfiled" />

        <add id="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled::menu"
             title="Add Rules"
             module="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled"
             sortOrder="100"
             parent="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled::VendoreName_addconditionfiled"
             action="addconditionfiled/index/index"
             resource="VendoreName_AddConditionFiled::menu"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

[Click Here For Part 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344612/82670)

[Click Here For Part 3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344613/82670)

**[Check condition with products in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344617/82670)**